# Filter rows in a column based on set rules in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I want to filter values on a column based on set rules

```
Group    ID
1      09239820
2      2872498938
2      1267
3      23219823983
3      267839236
4      33287442
```

I want to replace the 1st, 2nd and 4th numbers in the ID column with letters

```
Replace 1st with N
Replace 2nd with X
Replace 4TH with D
```

Expected output:

```
Group    ID
 1      NX2D9820
 2      NX7D498938
 2      NX6D
 3      NX2D9823983
 3      NX7D39236
 4      NX2D7442
```

Comment: try this, based on @cn007b answers: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4PESHVvFYuqBJNA62LHnZ3/0

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
Group,
CONCAT('NX', SUBSTRING(ID, 3, 1), 'D', SUBSTRING(ID, 5)) AS ID
FROM tableName;
```

Here we have concatenation of substrings:

```
CONCAT('NX', SUBSTRING(ID, 3, 1), 'D', SUBSTRING(ID, 5))
```

Where:

`'NX'` - 1st and 2nd characters,

`SUBSTRING(ID, 3, 1)` - 3d character as it is,

`'D'` - 4th character,

`SUBSTRING(ID, 5)` - rest of the string.

Comment: created fiddle based on your answer: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4PESHVvFYuqBJNA62LHnZ3/0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert`

```
select Group, insert(insert(ID,1,2,'NX'),4,1,'D')
from table;
```