# Replace values in column on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
     Group    ID           Values   Month
       1      09239820       43     May
       2      2872498938     23     Jan
       2      1267           18     Dec
       3      23219823983    09     Sept 
       3      267839236      11     July  
       4      33287442       23     Jan
```

I want to replace the 1st, 2nd and 4th numbers in the ID column with letters

```
 Replace 1st with N
 Replace 2nd with X
 Replace 4TH with D
```

Expected output:

```
    Group    ID           Value   Month
      1      NX2D9820       43      May
      2      NX7D498938     23      Jan 
      2      NX6D           18      Dec
      3      NX2D9823983    09      Sept
      3      NX7D39236      11      July
      4      NX2D7442       23      Jan
```

I am new to SQL, and I have written the following code below (it is not working)

```
SELECT * FROM #table# t1;
UPDATE t1 SET ID =  CONCAT('NX', SUBSTRING(ID,3,1), 'D', SUBSTRING(ID,5));
SELECT * FROM t1;
```

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104607/filter-rows-in-a-column-based-on-set-rules-in-sql.

Comment: @id'7238 ID column is int

Comment: @GordonLinoff Similar, but I have added extra columns & showed the code I used.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of doing this task, maybe it is not the simplest and fastest one but it make sense. If somebody think of any improvement on the query, feel free to edit my answer.

```
 UPDATE test_01 tbl1 
    INNER JOIN (
                    select `group`, concat_ws('',substring(RIGHT((insert(id, 1, 2, 'NX')), 9999),1,3), substring(LEFT((insert(id, 4, 1, 'D')), 9999),4,9999)) as id_tbl2 
                   from test_01)
     as tbl2   
    ON tbl1.`group` = tbl2.`group` 
    SET tbl1.id = tbl2.id_tbl2;
```

Working demo:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/6

**Let me explain what the query does**

> `insert(id, 1, 2, 'NX')` ---> inserts NX in first and second place
> `insert(id, 4, 1, 'D'`   ---> inserts D in the fourth place
> `substring(RIGHT((insert(id, 1, 2, 'NX')), 9999),1,3)` ---> select
> first three characters changed
> `substring(LEFT((insert(id, 4, 1, 'D')), 9999),4,9999)` ---> select from the fourth character to the end
> of the row because `9999` extends the column limit
>
> Using `concat_ws` I combine tha changed data to a new table and in the
> end we can update using the join condition.